# Common way to init UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c

I am using the following to `init` my table.

```
# AppDelegate.m
NSArray *textToPutInTable = @[@"Row One", @"Row More Than One", @"Row Hello!"];
ItemsViewController *itemsViewController = 
             [[ItemsViewController alloc] initWithTextToPutInTable:textToPutInTable];
self.window.rootViewController = itemsViewController;

# ItemsViewController.m
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.textToPutInTable[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Is there a better way to init a table? Or is the above pattern common in doing so?

Comment: The only think which should be done by the AppDelegate is to launch the initial view controller and respond to delegate methods. Don't put your model into the AppDelegate. I would define `textToPutInTable` within the init method of the `ItemsViewController`.

Comment: I see -- could you please show me that in an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: You mean a better way than an array to represent the data "behind" a table view?  Generally, no.  When and how that array is initialized depends on the source of the data, it's timing, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only think which should be done by the AppDelegate is to launch the initial view controller and respond to delegate methods. Don't put your model into the AppDelegate. I would define `textToPutInTable` within the init method of the `ItemsViewController`.

Edit:
I would do something like this:

```
@interface ItemsViewController () 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *textToPutInTable;
@end

@implementation

- (instancetype)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _textToPutInTable = @[@"Row One", @"Row More Than One", @"Row Hello!"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And in the AppDelegate:

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[ItemsViewController alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thanks, so how would I do the above `init`, putting all the code in `ItemsViewController`?